# Jenkins Console Output Error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We've been using Jenkins for a while now, but recently we've added a couple plug-ins to the configuration and our Console Output is not showing in real-time anymore, we just get a big fat Java error! I've removed the offending plug-ins (emotional jenkins and Green Spot) in an attempt to fix the problem, but I still get the errors. The Console output as plain text is fine though so there's no problem there. Has anyone experienced this or know what might be the problem? I've installed the plug-ins again to see if I can find some "extra" configuration that was added that I need to remove so the error is as follows: -
(this only happens while a build runs, the console output is blank showing nothing after it's finished)

```
Stack Trace

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:796)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:211)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$13.dispatch(MetaClass.java:411)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:123)
    at hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.extensions.ScmSyncConfigurationFilter$1.call(ScmSyncConfigurationFilter.java:46)
    at hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.ScmSyncConfigurationDataProvider.provideRequestDuring(ScmSyncConfigurationDataProvider.java:103)
    at hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.extensions.ScmSyncConfigurationFilter.doFilter(ScmSyncConfigurationFilter.java:42)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:120)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:135)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.collapsingconsolesections.CollapsingSectionsConfiguration.getSectionDefinitions(CollapsingSectionsConfiguration.java:56)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.collapsingconsolesections.CollapsingSectionNote$DescriptorImpl.getSectionDefinitions(CollapsingSectionNote.java:103)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.collapsingconsolesections.CollapsingSectionAnnotatorFactory.newInstance(CollapsingSectionAnnotatorFactory.java:40)
    at hudson.console.ConsoleAnnotator._for(ConsoleAnnotator.java:143)
    at hudson.console.ConsoleAnnotator.initial(ConsoleAnnotator.java:133)
    at hudson.console.AnnotatedLargeText.createAnnotator(AnnotatedLargeText.java:137)
    at hudson.console.AnnotatedLargeText.writeHtmlTo(AnnotatedLargeText.java:167)
    at hudson.console.AnnotatedLargeText.writeLogTo(AnnotatedLargeText.java:143)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.framework.io.LargeText.doProgressText(LargeText.java:262)
    at hudson.console.AnnotatedLargeText.doProgressiveHtml(AnnotatedLargeText.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:121)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    ... 78 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've removed the offending plug-ins (emotional jenkins and Green Spot) in an attempt to fix the problem, but I still get the errors.

The stack trace shows that Green Balls is still installed.

Have you followed the instructions at the top?

> 1. Please check [the Jenkins] bug tracker to see if a similar problem has already been reported.
> 2. If it is already reported, please vote and put a comment on it to let us gauge the impact of the problem.
> 3. If you think this is a new issue, please file a new issue.

In any case, the exception indicates that it was trigged by the Collapsing Console Sections plugin.

Comment: Hi, I did remove the plugins as mentioned but the errors for those plugins that appear in the stack trace are not there, it's still the same thing though, hence I put them back on again to see if I can find anything else. I also followed the instructions on bug tracking apart from logging the issue as it might be a problem I'm doing rather than a bug so I wanted to check here first :)

Comment: Jenkins recognised it as a bug, hence the text about the bug tracker. You shouldn't ever get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I have disabled the Collapsing Console Sections plugin. This appears to fix it move past the bug, I'm not sure why that is affected though from the installation of other plugins. Either way it doesn't affect the parts of Jenkins I use so I'll re-install it fresh, if that doesn't work I'll keep it removed.